# how to access the data according to key on json format

Tags: json

i have a api response data in this format

```
{
  "channel": [
    {
      "link": "https://www.foxnews.com",
      "title": "FOX News : World  ",
      "url": "https://global.fncstatic.com/static/orion/styles/img/fox-news/logos/fox-news-desktop.png"
    }
  ],
  "opstatus": 0,
  "httpStatusCode": 200
}
```

and want to print the `link` and `title` values. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import json

response =..  your json string;
jsonObj = json.loads(response)

print(jsonObj["channel"][0]["link"]) 
print(jsonObj["channel"][0]["title"]) 

//or if you have several objects in channel array

for each in jsonObj['channel']:
    print each['link']
```

Comment: How can you provide an answer if you don't know the language OP is working with (and never ask them either)?

Comment: @Marvin Only python developers asking about print